# Convert CommonJS require statement to load via an ES6 import?

Tags: es6-modules, commonjs

I would like to convert this CJS requires statement to load via an ES module import.
(I already have type: 'module' in my package.json)

`var https = require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();`

Comment: `ssl-root-cas/latest` does not appear to use ES6 exports. What transpiler solution are you using?

Comment: I'm using next.js which I believe uses webpack

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using...

```
import sslrootcas from 'ssl-root-cas';
https.globalAgent.ca = sslrootcas.create();
```

but i'm wondering if ES modules has a similar one-liner approach like CJS?